# python join lists to include full array even if columns are blank

Tags: python, list, join

I am joining two lists.

```
ListA
['5', 'h', 'k', '9', 'a', 'd', 'b']
ListB
[['x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['5', 'g', 'd'], ['w', '7', 'k']]
```

The result that I am getting is:

```
ListC
[['5', 'h', 'k', '9', 'a', 'd', 'b'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['5', 'g', 'd'], ['w', '7', 'k']]
```

I would like to create the full array of 5 rows x 7 columns such as shown below.

```
ListC
[['5', 'h', 'k', '9', 'a', 'd', 'b'], ['x', 'y', 'z','','','',''], ['a', 'b', 'c','','','',''], ['5', 'g', 'd','','','',''], ['w', '7', 'k','','','','']]
```

If possible I would like to do this without installing lambda, but if necessary I will.

Thanks in advance. My current code:

```
ListA = []
ListB = []
ListC = []

import csv
with open('List1.csv', newline='')as file1:
    reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
    for rowOfCells in reader1:
        ListA.append(rowOfCells)      
with open('List2.csv', newline='')as file2:
    reader2 = csv.reader(file2)
    for rowOfCells in reader2:
        ListB.append(rowOfCells)

ListC = ListA + ListB

print (ListC)

with open("ListC",'w', newline= '') as outFile:
    wr = csv.writer(outFile, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerows(ListC)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "empty columns", empty strings?

Comment: Please include the expected output. It's not clear from your question. Especially the origin of five rows. The best interpretation I can make of your question gives 4 x 7.

Comment: sorry guys, I am new at this.

I would like the following.  I get out of range errors when I try to access for columns 3-6 after the first row.

    ['5', 'h', 'k', '9', 'a', 'd', 'b']
    ['x', 'y', 'z','','','','']
    ['a', 'b', 'c','','','','']
    ['5', 'g', 'd','','','','']
    ['w', '7', 'k','','','','']

Comment: I'm looking for a way to join two lists that gives me the full array.  Greatest number of columns of either list x greatest number of rows of either list.  I want to populate the cells that currently have empty strings.  The way that I have done it, the cells are not created.  It is not a fully rectangular array.  Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused. CSV writer requires a nested list: The outermost list is the dataset, and then lists nested within that represent one row. There should be no need at all to pad any row with empty strings to get your rows aligned. EDIT: We commented at the same time. Does `writerows` (noting the s at the end) really cause this to be misaligned?

Comment: Could a solution be to use CSV writer to write ListC to a csv file, then read it back in?

Comment: If the cells written need to explicitly contain empty strings then I suggest maybe the answer from Thomas. Don't write to a file needlessly to read it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> ListC = [['5', 'h', 'k', '9', 'a', 'd', 'b'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['5', 'g', 'd'], ['w', '7', 'k']]
>>> ListC = [(e + [''] * (len(max(ListC, key=len)) - len(e))) for e in ListC]
>>> print ListC
[['5', 'h', 'k', '9', 'a', 'd', 'b'], ['x', 'y', 'z', '', '', '', ''], ['a', 'b', 'c', '', '', '', ''], ['5', 'g', 'd', '', '', '', ''], ['w', '7', 'k', '', '', '', '']]
```